# How to define a nested struct in MASM?

Tags: assembly, struct, masm

I'm trying to define a nested struct in MASM, but the errors are not very helpful, and I can't find any reference.

A simple example is the following:

```
        .const

child   struct
value   byte   ?
child   ends

parent  struct
Id      byte   ?
Child   child  {}
parent  ends

      .data

; ok
Parent1 parent {1}

; Error A2151: Missing operator in expression
; Error A2233: Invalid data initializer: Child
Parent2 parent {1, child {1}}
```

What do I need to corrent in `Parent2`'s definition?

Comment: Not sure where you got that `{}` syntax from(?). I'm pretty sure it should be `<>`.

Comment: Ok, the manual says that `<>` and `{}` are both valid. So the problem appears to be that you named the second initializer. That is, remove `child` and just write `Parent2 parent {1, {1}}`

Comment: @Michael Thanks! If you turn this into an answer, I'll accept. The syntax, by the way, comes from "The Art of 64-Bit Assembly".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MASM 6.1 Programmer's Guide lists these syntax variants for defining variables of Structure or Union type:

```
[[name]] typename < [[initializer [[,initializer]]...]] >
[[name]] typename { [[initializer [[,initializer]]...]] }
[[name]] typename constant DUP ({ [[initializer [[,initializer]]...]] })
```

The initializers, if provided, should just be values corresponding in type to the field defined in the type declaration.

So to define a `parent` variable with an `Id` of 1 and a `Child.value` of 2, you could write:

```
Parent2 parent {1, {2}}
```